# How to send parameters with Angular's $http.delete()?

Tags: angularjs, rest

This is how I use Angular's $http.get to send parameters to a REST endpoint. It works:

```
var httpParams = {'myparam1': 'Hello'};
$http.get('http://localhost:8976/my/url', {'params': httpParams}).then(successFunc, failureFunc);
```

This sends a GET call that is equivalent to the following CURL command:

```
curl --request GET "http://localhost:8976/my/url?myparam1=Hello"
```

But now want to send a DELETE request with the same URL and the same parameters. How do I do it? This doesn't work:

```
var httpParams = {'myparam1': 'Hello'};
$http.delete('http://localhost:8976/my/url', {'params': httpParams}).then(successFunc, failureFunc);
```

The URL gets hit, but the parameters are not received by the REST endpoint.

Comment: `$http.delete("http://localhost:8976/my/url?" + httpParams)`

Comment: Sorry, Sravan, that isn't correct. You cannot concatenate an object and a string like that.

Comment: `var httpParams = $.param({
    'myparam1': 'Hello'
});`, use `$.param` to convert it into query params.

Comment: checked with that?

Comment: Hmm, that is odd. What backend are you using to serve up your endpoints? Can you confirm in the client dev tools that the request contains the query parameters in the URL?

Comment: Which angular and browser are you using ?

Comment: Sravan, yes. Your second solution worked. Thanks!!!
But why doesn't $http.delete() work the same way as $http.get()? It seems like they should behave analogously.

Answer (score 1):

For handling `REST`ful things you  should use [`Angular#$resource`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource) which provide `delete` method on each resource object.And you can configure the `params` as well during resource configuration and creation.

Using resource,you can have `CRUD API` without manual configuration.
so,http `GET,POST,DELET,PUT` method on this resource object

If you want to send DELETE REST manually then better 
pass the parameter as query string.It does not send the parameter in the body.